# Laravel 5: Routing

Tags: laravel

Laravel, 5.0.2,

Скажите друзья, как самому создать свой контроллер ПРАВИЛЬНО?

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index');
Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index');
```

Первые 3 контроллера работают, они изначально были.

Я добавил NewsController,

```
class NewsController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
            return "News!";
        }
}
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

    in RouteCollection.php line 145
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Уже, не знаю в чем проблема. Я только начал изучать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы `composer dump-autoload` делали? Если вы используете namaspace, после создания нового класса стоит выполнять эту команду.

Answer (score 1):

Предоставьте полный код контролера.

Важный момент: после открытия тега `<?php`
Вы должны указать что данный класс находиться (**по дефолту**) в `App\Http\Controllers` неймспейсе.
То есть у вас должно получиться что-то такое:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers
class NewsController extends Controller {
...
```

Так же учтите, что файл должен находиться в директории `app/Http/Controllers/`
Так же учтите что ваш файл должен называться точно так же как и название класса. В вашем случаи это: `NewsController.php`

И да, используйте команду `php artisan make:controller NewsController` для правильного создания контролера.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь `composer` для создания контроллеров.

Обычный контроллер:
перейти в директорию проекта командой сd (например `cd myfolder/myproject`)

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController
```

Контроллер ресурсов (c готовыми методами для работы с ресурсами):
перейти в директорию проекта командой сd (например `cd myfolder/myproject`)

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

Comment: Осмелюсь спросить, а в чём разница контроллеров, обычного от ресурсов?